# Expand content below controls

Tags: c#, xaml, expand, expander

Hey below is very simple code of an expander in action. Currently the expander will expand a text block and the radio buttons below it will move down. I would like to have the radio buttons stay where they are and display the text block below them whilst also keeping the expander icon in it's current location. Thanks!

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Expender WPF Sample" Height="300" Width="400"
    >
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"  Margin="10,5,0,0">
                <RadioButton Content="Choice One"/>
                <RadioButton Content="Choice Two"/>
                <RadioButton Content="Choice Three"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <Expander HorizontalAlignment="Right" Header="" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" ExpandDirection="Down" Width="150">
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Background="AntiqueWhite">
                This is the standard expander
                behavior.  The expander opens
                and the controls below it 
                move down.
            </TextBlock>
        </Expander>

    </Grid>


</Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Expander HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" ExpandDirection="Down" Width="150">
                <Expander.Header>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"  Margin="10,5,0,0">
                        <RadioButton Content="Choice One"/>
                        <RadioButton Content="Choice Two"/>
                        <RadioButton Content="Choice Three"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Expander.Header>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Background="AntiqueWhite">
                This is the standard expander
                behavior.  The expander opens
                and the controls below it 
                move down.
                </TextBlock>
            </Expander>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: I've tried putting the data as the header. However, I want to hide the the expander icon by setting the expander's visibility to hidden. This will in turn also hide the radio buttons which I don't want to do.

Comment: So why you need Expander here...Without icon how can user use this functionality.

Comment: To elaborate, I want the icon hidden when the mouse is outside the window and the icon visible when the mouse enters the window. Look at a simple google news article as an example. news.google.com

Comment: Use Triggers or write code on mouse over event to fix this issue.